# Is it possible to set optimization level on Microsoft SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, performance, optimization, query-performance

I would like to ask if there is a way to set the optimization level for SQL Server like it can be done on DB2/Sybase ASE/Oracle. The reason for this question is that I belive that SQL Server may not be choosing hash join for some cases.

Examples for other DBMS:

- *DB2* - [SET CURRENT QUERY OPTIMIZATION](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_9.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0001007.html)
- *Sybase ASE* - [SELECT @@optlevel](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00743.1570/html/queryprocessing/queryprocessing159.htm)
- *Oracle* - [PLSQL_OPTIMIZE_LEVEL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/initparams184.htm#REFRN10255)